# Interpretation of completed tensor product of algebras over lower base

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $\mathbb F$ be a finite field of order $q = p^n$. It is known that

$$\mathbb F[[x_1]] \mathbin{\widehat{\otimes}_{\mathbb F}} \mathbb F[[x_2]] = \mathbb F[[x_1, x_2]].$$ Geometrically, this is the completed local ring at a smooth closed point of a $2$-dimensional scheme over $\mathbb F$.

Is there a similarly nice characterisation of
$$\mathbb F[[x_1]] \mathbin{ \widehat{\otimes}_{\mathbb F_p}} \mathbb F[[x_2]]$$
in case $\mathbb F \neq \mathbb F_p$? Can it be viewed as some inverse limit of finitely generated algebras?

My guess is that this is the ring of power series $\sum_{(k_1, k_2) \in \mathbb N^2} a_{k_1, k_2} x_1^{k_1} x_2^{k_2}$ with coefficients in $\mathbb F$ such that for each power series $f$ there exists a constant $c_f$ such that if $k_1 \geq c_f$ and $k_2 \geq c_f$, we have $a_{k_1, k_2} \in \mathbb F_p$.

Is this correct? Is there a (somewhat) natural geometric interpretation of this ring? I am interested in higher-dimensional analogues, too.

Comment: Love your name.

Comment: Note that $\mathbb F[\![T]\!]\cong\mathbb F_p[\![T]\!]\otimes_{\mathbb F_p}\mathbb F$, or more generally, tensoring with a pseudocoherent complex preserves infinite products, \[SP, [Tag 0CYB](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0CYB)\].